# Hidden Rippple Effect in android - Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, hide, effects, ripple

Having background color set on the xamarin forms Layout Hides the ripple effect in android. Has anyone found a work around on this. Is this a bug on xamarin forms?

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="listTemplate">
        <ViewCell> 
            <ViewCell.View>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Margin="0,0,0,3">

                </Frame>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
```